# How can I aggregate a count of a value in column based on calendar week and year

Tags: r

```
    Date        Stock
              
1   2017-10-19  F5 Blue
2   2017-10-19  F5 Blue
3   2017-10-19  F5 Blue
4   2017-10-30  F5 Green
5   2017-10-30  F6 Blue
6   2017-10-31  F6 Green
7   2017-10-31  F6 Green
```

I have quite a large dataset (2017 to 2020) and I would like to count each occurrence of "Stock" per week for the whole data set. So I would like to see (just for this example of 7)

```
2017-10-19 to 2017-10-26 F5 Blue = 3
2017-10-27 to 2017-11-2  F5 Green = 1 F6 Green = 2 F6 Blue = 1
```

I have been looking around and cannot find

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `group_by` with `summarise`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   group_by(Week = lubridate::week(Date), Stock) %>%
   summarise(n = n(), .groups = 'drop')
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 4 x 3
#   Week Stock       n
#  <dbl> <chr>   <int>
#1    42 F5Blue      3
#2    44 F5Green     1
#3    44 F6Blue      1
#4    44 F6Green     2
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(Date = structure(c(17458, 17458, 17458, 17469, 
17469, 17470, 17470), class = "Date"), Stock = c("F5Blue", "F5Blue", 
"F5Blue", "F5Green", "F6Blue", "F6Green", "F6Green")), row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the week information from date and count :

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% count(Week = lubridate::week(Date), Stock)

#  Week   Stock n
#1   42  F5Blue 3
#2   44 F5Green 1
#3   44  F6Blue 1
#4   44 F6Green 2
```

In base R you can use `table` :

```
table(format(df$Date, '%V'), df$Stock)
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(Date = structure(c(17458, 17458, 17458, 17469, 
17469, 17470, 17470), class = "Date"), Stock = c("F5Blue", "F5Blue", 
"F5Blue", "F5Green", "F6Blue", "F6Green", "F6Green")), row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: I seem to be getting this error in that first solution consistently. Error in UseMethod("group_by_") : 
  no applicable method for 'group_by_' applied to an object of class "function"

Comment: @Gamecocks20 Did the 2nd method work for you? For the 1st method try writing `dplyr::count`. Can you test this on the data which I have shared in my post? Does it work on that data?